# What is a quantifier in game-based definitions?

Tags: provable-security, security-definition

I'd like to know what are quantifiers in game-based security definitions (in cryptography)

Some relevant examples and sources are also much appreciated.

---

Edit: for example, in a formal definition, we say for any security parameters, any function $F$, etc. My question is what should be included in these quantifiers (shall we include everything picked deterministically by the experiment?)is there any clear rule we need to follow?

Comment: A bit of context might be helpful.

Comment: @Maeher thanks for the comment! I have added more text.